# Typo3 Indexed_search will index metadata information from DAM tables?

Tags: typo3

I am using the DAM module. Does indexed search index the meta data from tx_dam tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, indexed_search only indexes the frontend output of cached pages. So if you add descriptions to your images coming from DAM, the data will be indexed. But not directly.